# How to get list of class methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following class in JavaScript.

```js
class User {
  get(id) {
    return {id};
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of the methods from an instance.

```js
const user = new User();
```

Basically this means, I'm trying to find code where the input is `user` and the output is `["get"]`.

I have tried the following, but they all print `[]` (which is not what I expect).

```js
console.log(Object.keys(user)); // []
console.log(Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(user))); // []
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user)); // []
```

I know `user.get` exists because the following line works and prints `[Function: get]`:

```js
console.log(user.get); // [Function: get]
```

Obviously this works for properties, and prototype functions. But I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work with class methods. So that means that any solution can not change the `User` class.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user.__proto__)` will output `["constructor", "get"]` ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guv4n0d3/))

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the prototype of the instance first:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(u)));
```

prints

```
["constructor", "get"]
```